# How to pass data to child with ng-content in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I would like to create a generic component for a `table`/`tr`/`td`

So I have this:

```
            <Datatable [data]="results">
                <DatatableColumn [field]="name">1</DatatableColumn>
                <DatatableColumn>2</DatatableColumn>
                <DatatableColumn>3</DatatableColumn>
                <DatatableColumn>4</DatatableColumn>
            </Datatable>
```

And this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Datatable',
  template: `
    <table>
        <tr #lineSelected *ngFor="let subscription of data">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </tr>
    </table>
  `,
  })
  export class DatatableComponent {

      @Input()
      data: Object;

  }
```

I would like to pass data to `ng-content` (which it has to display `<td>`) :

Example : `<ng-content [dataRow]="subscription"></ng-content>`

By this way, I could use `dataRow` in my Child component. Something like `dataRow.field`

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'DatatableColumn',
   template:`
     <td>
        dataRow.field
     </td>
   `
  })
  export class DatatableColumnComponent {
      @Input()
      field: String;
  }
```

I don't know how to write it. Any help please?

Thanks